# How to fetch blog posts by month using MONTH() in mySQLi

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

I have my datetime going into the DB like this:

```
$CurrentTime = time();
$DateTime = strftime("%b-%d-%Y %H: %M: %S", $CurrentTime);
```

In phpMyAdmin it looks like this:

```
May-15-2018 01: 04: 00
Feb-08-2018 13: 49: 23
etc...
```

The field is `varchar(50)`

I'm trying to extract posts from this table based on the month that the post was created.

I have tried the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE MONTH(datetime) ='2'"
"SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%b-%d-%Y %H: %M: %S')) ='2'"
```

I don't get an error, but nothing is returning.  Any ideas on how I can correct this?

Comment: try this i hope DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%m') =2

Comment: I tried this (no errors) but did not get any return.  datetime is the name of the column. 
 `"SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%m') ='2'"`

Comment: yes  remove ' quotation on 2. than you will get the result.

Comment: You should use 2 and not '2'. Do like this: `SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(datetime, '%b-%d-%Y %H: %M: %S')) = 2`

Comment: I have removed the quotations & still the same thing; no error, but no result.  Does the fact that it is varchar make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use MYSQL STR_TO_DATE with MONTH**

```
"SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`,'%b-%e-%Y %H:%i:%s')) = 5"
```

> Adding Year with AND condition

```
SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`,'%b-%e-%Y %H:%i:%s')) = 5 AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`,'%b-%e-%Y %H:%i:%s')) = 2018
```

Comment: thanks for this, however I'm still not getting any return.

Comment: When I run `SELECT * FROM admin_panel` I get all of the records.  Did this to test & works fine.  When I specify the month using your method, I get no returns.  I have 5 records that are February.

Comment: awesome.  and if I wanted to include YEAR in that query could I just than add `AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`,'%b-%e-%Y %H:%i:%s')) = 2017)` ?

Comment: if it work for you, then you can mark it as answer thanks

Comment: I've tried this, `SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`,'%b-%e-%Y %H:%i:%s')) = 2 AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`datetime`,'%b-%e-%Y %H:%i:%s')) = 2018)` but now not getting a return.  I realize not part of original question but for learning, what is missing from AND portion?

Comment: i have tested and it is working for me with AND condition too, your condition is fine

Answer (score 0):

The following works when the 'datetime' column is defined as DATETIME, yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s (2018-06-14 14:29:15) and not as VARCHAR,

```
SELECT * FROM admin_panel where extract(month from datetime)='02'
```

I think, if you use a VARCHAR instead of a DATE.. type, then you will have to typecast string to a date for performing any date-based functions on it in a query. Imo, it is better to have date stored in DATE.. format and let MySQL store it in some format; but you could format it using DATE_FORMAT functions for displaying.

When column type is DATETIME, month() call also can be used as in,

```
SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE month(datetime)='02'
```